# gitlab throwing - failed to store ssl session

Tags: git, gitlab

I am getting below error into pull,push etc git command.

fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/test/test.git/': failed to store ssl session

Answer (score -1):

Please delete password file from your pc/laptop.

The path for the password file is C:..\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree

I did and my issue resolved please try.