# Git returns "Failed to store ssl session"

Tags: git, ssl

I am asking this question as the answer for the [one previously posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53755626/github-throwing-failed-to-store-ssl-session) doesn't seem to fit as a solution. I tried to look up the file location the member mentioned but it doesn't exist.

Keep in mind this is a work computer I am using and I do have a ticket elevated but they are taking too long and I am trying to get an answer quickly.

Below is the error with my repo removed

> fatal: unable to access (REPO URL): failed to store ssl session

It is installed on Windows 10. Any command that tries to communicate with bitbucket. (Clone, Push, Pull) and the ticket is with my companies help desk.

Comment: What platform are you on? What command are you issuing to get this error? Who have you raised a ticket with? Please edit the question with this information.

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was in environmental variables and .npmrc file.I had the proxy settings of
HTTP_PROXY= http://example.com
HTTPS_PROXY= http://example.com

Deleted both the keys and re-opened command prompt. Issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin was removed from my systems path. Simple fix after a major headache of multiple uninstall and reinstalls and other failed avenues.